# jquery .hide/show form still sends data to the controller

Tags: jquery

Simple, if the #parentPermission is hidden, it send post variable of (parentPermission) to the controller, there are two variables that works by sending the id=link to the controller, if one is hidden then it should not send the data, but usually what happens that it does not recognize html select #link form.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    toggleFields(); 
    $("#link").click(function () {
        toggleFields();
    });
});

//this toggles the visibility of our parent permission fields depending on the current selected value of the underAge field

function toggleFields() {
    if ($("#link").val() == 'other')
        $("#parentPermission").show();
    else
        $("#parentPermission").hide();
}
```

HTML mvc View :

```
    <!-- Select Basic -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="assign_article">Assign Article to Menu</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <select id="link" name="link" class="form-control">

      <?php 

                foreach($get_data as $ShowMenu) { ?>

          <option value="<?php echo $ShowMenu['id']; ?>"><?php  echo $ShowMenu['title']; ?></option>


        <?php } ?>


        <option id="parent" value="parent">Other</option>

        </select>






      </div>
          </div>



  <!-- Text input-->
    <div id="parentPermission" class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="menu_name">Other:</label>
      <div id="parentPermission" class="col-md-4">
        <input id="parentPermission" name="link" type="text" placeholder="menu name" class="form-control input-md">
        </div>
    </div>

       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    toggleFields(); //call this first so we start out with the correct visibility depending on the selected form values
    //this will call our toggleFields function every time the selection value of our underAge field changes
    $("#link").change(function () {
        toggleFields();
    });

});
//this toggles the visibility of our parent permission fields depending on the current selected value of the underAge field
function toggleFields() {
    if ($("#link").val() == 'parent')
        $("#parentPermission").show();

    else
        $("#parentPermission").hide();
}
</script>

    <!-- Select Basic -->
```

Comment: I don't see what would prevent data being sent, or how exactly the data sending is triggered. Please update!

Comment: Same as Vlad, if you use hide, it will add display:none to your object, it would not prevent data being sent, what you have to do is block the trigger that sends the data.

Comment: If you don't want the form to be submitted you can always just target each input and clear its value

Comment: @FelipeCh. Yes! Is there any way I can prevent data from being sent. Please code

Comment: @VladPintea Yes, it is good that you recognised what I desire, can you help me code it please..

Comment: I can't even give you a hint given the lack of details here. Please update, show some of the markup, what controller gets triggered and when, and we can see what you need to be doing

Comment: @VladPintea edit the article please check, before you help keep in mind that am w3school guy in jquery

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the issue using if statement in the php however it was much difficult for the jquery to not to send the data using the .remove function